# Android GPS: android.location.Location what significance do latitude/longitude fractional digits have?

Tags: android, gps, digits

I'm using GPS on an android phone. In a small test app I get like up to 15 fractional digits (sorry, too lazy to count exactly) for the latitude and longitude. I know that GPS on a handheld device is not really accurate, so why are there so many fractional digits? I'm not having any code issue, just curious. ;-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPS chip internally uses 7 digits after decimal point,  when providing the result in the binary protocol,
more digits make no sense. (Thats about 1 cm accuracy at aequator)
For many applications 6 digits or for display even 5 digits are sufficient.

You also may want to look at 
[GPS coordinates accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528255/gps-coordinates-accuracy/15546466#15546466)

Comment: So are the digits 8 to ~15 just random or do they make sense at any point?

Comment: You can call them random but a better word is artefacts or side effect, probably the are from converting an float to double or int to float or double, or from floating point representation in general. (like 1/3 = 1.3333333333333; the same principle exist for binary represention of a decimal value, such simple decimal value like 0.1 need theoretically unlimited number of binary digits)

Comment: The maximum what makes sense are 7 digits the rest are useless and unwanted rounding effects, as explained above.